# grep file extension present inside file

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, grep, command

I am trying to find ".eml" inside files but I am getting all sort of text which ends with the "eml" or present with "eml" in the texts.

How can I search the particular ".eml" text present on the files.

> $ grep -rsin "*.eml" --exclude-dir=cache src/

Command I am trying right now. Eaxmple text which i am receiving are "yuimenuit**eml**abel" but its wrong.

I am looking for some thing like this "text.eml" or "sendemail.eml" similar to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `.eml` will match any caracter `.` followed by `eml`. You must escape the dot :

```
grep -rsin "\.eml" --exclude-dir=cache src/
```

Comment: woked will..  but it didnt get me all th lists